Функции в переменных JS


var addFive1 = function addFive1(num) {
  return num + 2
};

console.log(addFive1(14))



Получу я 16.
В console.log я вызову переменную с функцией или саму функцию?
Так как переменная и сама функция имеют одинаковое название, мне интересно, что будет использоваться.
Если менять название то результат не поменяется.

Пример из книги javascript с нуля до профи

ты вызовешь функцию

в консоль лог вызовется функция, в которую, в качестве аргумента будет передано число 14. В функции 14 будет присвоено переменной num и функция вернет результат сложения num + 2 = 16, что и отображается в консоли

я вызову переменную с функцией или саму функцию - чем отличается первое от второго?

Считай что ты используешь микс function declaration и function expression..... суть всё равно одна - ты вызваешь функцию по итогу

@АлексейШиманский, тут нет никакого микса

@Grundy да, соглы)   значит только function expression)) тем становится однозначней всё

имя FunctionExpression доступно только внутри этого выражение

Спасибо всем, теперь я узнал о терминах function declaration и function expression
